# Дублирование вывода на консоль при срабатывании FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, файлы, консоль

Юзаю этот код. Скопировал с рабочего стола два `txt` файла, и ctrl+v в директорию которую отслеживает FileSystemWatcher. После вставки файлов в папку на консоль вывод дублируется следующим образом https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1Qzx.png

Почему так?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path);

    watcher.Changed += OnChanged;

    watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    Console.ReadLine();
}
private static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Changed: {e.FullPath}");
}
```

Comment: [Пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764809/filesystemwatcher-changed-event-is-raised-twice) что это баг/фича

Comment: @Vasek понятно, спасибо

Comment: Не могу воспроизвести. Какая операционная система? Вас все еще интересует решение этой проблемы? Судя по показанному коду у вас вообще ничего не должно произойти, потому что вы не подписываетесь на `watcher.Created`. Никакого вывода в консоль вообще не должно быть. То есть текст вопроса не соответствует коду.

Comment: Вот если я обычным нотпадом открою файл, а потом сделаю "сохранить как" и выберу новое имя для файла, то получаю следующую последовательность событий `Created`-`Deleted`-`Created`-`Changed` для нового файла (гениальное решение от Microsoft, я считаю). А вы как именно тестировали, чтобы получить двойное событие? Какие действия предшествовали копированию? Или все-таки это было не копирование?

Comment: @Vasek здесь речь про explorer, а не про notepad же.

Comment: @aepot если правильно понял, то это генерик проблема, не зависящая от конкретной программы

Comment: @aepot Я просто сделал ctrl+c с рабочего стола и ctrl+v в папку за которой следит ```FileSystemWatcher```. ОС - Windows 10. Больше никаких действий не делал. И с ```watcher.Created``` всё нормально, выводит один раз. Я следил именно на директорий, а не конкретным файлом.

Comment: Использую тот же код, что и вы, тоже слежу за каталогом, обозначенной проблемы в explorer не наблюдаю. Win 10 20H2. Для проверки подписался на все 4 доступных события. Другими словами при реализации учитывайте тот факт, что проблема может быть, а может и не быть.

Comment: @Vasek как раз зависящая. Сколько системных вызовов с обращениями к файловой системе приложение сделает, столько событий и прилетит. Потом, у меня например ее вообще нет. Может от дисковой системы еще зависит, а конкретно от поведения драйвера.

Comment: Посмотрите на параметр NotifyFilter, может он чем-то поможет. А ещё можно вынести ``static FileSystemEventArgs last``; и сверять, если у последнего и текущего некие ключевые поля совпали (e.FullPath, e.ChangeType) - то считать повтором.